# Java Static Elements Getting accessed by different class

Tags: java, types, static, primitive-types, modifiers

In Java Static elements are getting accessed by specifying only the Class name followed by `dot` operator.

Assume, I have a Class named **ClassA** with a static primitive type `int a = 10;`

What If I have other two class **ClassB** and **ClassC** access the element `a` at same time and make some change, will the change made by **ClassB** also impacts in the **ClassC** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What If I have other two class `ClassB` and `ClassC` access the element a at same time and make some change, will the change made by `ClassB` also impacts in the `ClassC` ?

There's only one `ClassA.a`, because it's a static member. The change made by `ClassB` impacts **`ClassA.a`**. `ClassC` will see the change because it's looking at that same member.

The scenario you describe is better expressed in code and diagrams:

The classes:

```
class ClassA {
    static int a = 10;
}

class ClassB {
    static void look() {
        System.out.println("B sees " + ClassA.a);
    }
    static void change() {
        ClassA.a = 42;
    }
}

class ClassC {
    static void look() {
        System.out.println("C sees " + ClassA.a);
    }
    static void change() {
        ClassA.a = 67;
    }
}
```

Using them:

```
ClassB.look(); // "B sees 10"
ClassC.look(); // "C sees 10"
ClassB.change();
ClassB.look(); // "B sees 42"
ClassC.look(); // "C sees 42"
ClassC.change();
ClassB.look(); // "B sees 67"
ClassC.look(); // "C sees 67"
```

Diagrams:

```
                         +----------+
                         |  ClassA  |
                         +----------+
                  +-+--->| static a |
                  | |    +----------+
+-----------+     | |
|  ClassB   |     | |
+-----------+     | |
| (methods) |-use-+ |
+-----------+       |
                    |
+-----------+       |
|  ClassC   |       |
+-----------+       |
| (methods) |-use---+
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Static fields are relevant to the class and not the instance.  A modification to a static field will cause all references to that field to return the last value assigned.  In a sense, `A` is now defined as a global variable within your application, under most use cases this is not consider a good thing.

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();

        System.out.println(A.a); //outputs 10
        b.changeA();
        System.out.println(A.a); //outputs 30
        c.changeA();
        System.out.println(A.a); //outputs 20
    }
}

class A{
    static int a = 10;
}

class B{
    public void changeA(){
        A.a = 30;
    }
}

class C{
    public void changeA(){
        A.a = 20;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kevin. In the example provided by you the Class 'App' does create instance of ClassB and ClassC in same program, but what if ClassB is in one Class name it as 'App1' and ClassC in another class 'App2' and these 2 classes are run separately but at same time. what happens to the ClassA static element ?